# PostgreSQL WHERE IN clause variation

Tags: postgresql, select, where-in

**Fictional example**

```
SELECT products_campaign.id
FROM products_campaign 
INNER JOIN products_store ON products_campaign.id_campaign = products_store.id_campaign 
WHERE products_store.id_store in (100, 200, 300)
GROUP BY id
```

This brings me every product id that is in store 100, 200 **OR** 300.
I want to build a query that gives me every product id that is in store 100, 200 **AND** 300, that is, the product has to exist in all three stores (intersect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_agg()` with the operator`@>`:

```
SELECT products_campaign.id
FROM products_campaign 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_campaign
    FROM products_store 
    GROUP BY id_campaign
    HAVING (array_agg(id_store) @> array[100, 200, 300])
    ) products_store
ON products_campaign.id_campaign = products_store.id_campaign 
GROUP BY id
```

Read about [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

Comment: Can you post a link to documentation or something explaining the `@>` operator please?

Comment: The `@>` operator means simply `contains`, see the link in the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products_campaign.id
FROM products_campaign 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT pc.id, count(distinct ps.id_store)
     FROM products_campaign pc
     INNER JOIN products_store ps 
     ON pc.id_campaign = ps.id_campaign 
     AND ps.id_store in (100,200,300)
     GROUP BY pc.id
     HAVING count(distinct ps.id_store) = 3
) intersection
ON intersection.id = products_campaign.id 
INNER JOIN products_store 
ON products_campaign.id_campaign = products_store.id_campaign 
GROUP BY products_campaign.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT products_campaign.id
FROM products_campaign 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM products_store WHERE id_store = 100) AS a 
   ON products_campaign.id_campaign = a.id_campaign
 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM products_store WHERE id_store = 200) AS b 
   ON products_campaign.id_campaign = a.id_campaign

 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM products_store WHERE id_store = 300) AS c 
   ON products_campaign.id_campaign = a.id_campaign

GROUP BY id
```

If it doesn't, please post your create table statements, and show what you expect as output